# Python 3.3| cx_Freeze py to exe work! But displays an error after build

Tags: python, build, exe, cx-freeze, setup.py

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:\Python33'lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py",
line 27, in<module>
    exec(code, m._dict))
File "smtpMail.py", line 30, in <module>
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\VideoCapture\_init_.py",line
62, in_init_
    os.path.join(_path_[0], 'helvetica-10.pil'))
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 273, in
load_path
    raise IOError(cannot find font file)
OSError: cannot find font file
```

Image Errorת, When playing the file:
http://s14.postimg.org/4pek1fwld/cx_Freeze.jpg

My program is based on the number of modules.
In my main file - 'smtpMail.py' my modules are:

```
import smtplib, platform, os, datetime
import socket

from VideoCapture import Device
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from win32com.client import GetObject
```

I think my mistake in the setup.py file of the build cx_Freeze
What I need is to know how to edit right the setup.py file.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "smtpMail",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("smtpMail.py", base=base)])
```

Who can help me please? :)

**Updating:**

The problem is in the 'VideoCapture' module - I think.
I edit the file like this:

```
import sys 
import smtplib, platform, os, datetime
import socket

from VideoCapture import Device
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from win32com.client import GetObject
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["smtplib","platform","os","datetime","socket","VideoCapture","PIL"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "smtpMail",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("smtpMail.py", base=base)])
```

And it don't work - Made the same error again.
So I mark all the related to the 'VideoCapture' module in the stmpMail.py as a comment.

and Walla!! the exe file work.
So now, who can help me, and tell me who I fix it?

**P.S.**

I read the cx-freeze document,

http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html

But that still does not help me. Help Please? :)

Comment: The VideoCapture module is trying to load a data file from its own directory. That probably won't work when it's frozen into a zip file. Have a look at this bit of the docs on using data files: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files